# get returned result after click event in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that return value and i executed the function after click event for example

```
$("some_div").click( my_function());
```

The answer is how to get the returned value of the function.

i couldn't use

```
var something = $("some_div").click( my_function());
```

---

Thanks to every one who contribute the the question.I've got my answer.

Comment: what are you intending to do with the returned value?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a **function** to `click`, not its *return value*. In the event handler you can call your function and deal with the return value as you see fit:

```
$("some_div").click(function() {
    var result = my_function();
    // do whatever you want with `result`
});
```

The event handler is not called immediately, but some time later (when the element is clicked). Therefore it does not make sense for `.click` to return a value.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a global Variable and write the result into that. Here is an example that writes the current event into global:

```
var global = ''

$("#some_div").click(function(e){
  global = e;
});
```

Comment: Yea you are right, I just copy/pasted his code and didn't look closer. I will change it.

Comment: I actually have a function that corespond withREST service with AJAX using $.ajax of JQuery, and i nead the reurnd information about curent session.

Something like that

$("button").click(function(){

var sess_data = ajx_function_call();

})

Comment: It works the other way round. The ajax call has a return function where you can work with the return values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a return value, You only subsrcibe a `callback` function that will be fire when clicking "some_div".

If you want to use some value from `callback` function, use it inside the function or save it in a `hidden input`

```
$("some_div").click(function() {
    var someValue = foo();
    $('#hiddenInputName').val(someValue);
});

//later on...

var extractedValue = $('#hiddenInputName').val();
```