# How do I catch the response from a named function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function like this:

```
$('.qa-nav-main-ask a').click(showAskForm);
```

Show showAskForm is this (simplified):

```
    function showAskForm(){
        return true;
    }
```

I want to catch the response from showAskForm and save it to a variable, I tried

```
askFormShowing = $('.qa-nav-main-ask a').click(showAskForm);
```

without success.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976347/get-returned-result-after-click-event-in-jquery)

Comment: what do you mean by return = true ? it should be return true; not?

Comment: @C-link It's more fun when questions have a syntax error not directly related to the actual intent ..

Comment: (For OP: `return` is a *reserved word* and *cannot* be used as a JavaScript identifier; all forms of `return = true` result in a SyntaxError.)

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how event handlers / the execution flow work in JavaScript. The line `askFormShowing = $('.qa-nav-main-ask a').click(showAskForm);` can *never* work. The event handler is **not** executed at the moment you are binding it, so you cannot receive its return value. The event handler is only executed as *response* to some user interaction (a click in this case). The return value would be returned to the code that calls your event handler as response of this interaction, which is browser internal code, not your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function showAskForm(){
    return true;
}

var askFormShowing; 
$('.qa-nav-main-ask a').click(function(){askFormShowing = showAskForm();});
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

`return` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a JavaScript identifier. So, use like this:

```
$('.qa-nav-main-ask a').click(showAskForm);

function showAskForm(){
        myvar = true;
    }
```